# Un arreglo que no de el mismo resultado 1 a 2 veces seguidas

Tags: javascript, html, array

Mi programa en js. Lo que quiero hacer es que cada vez que se aplaste un botón con una función se active esto, pero el problema es que el resultado se repite seguido y es molesto.

```
var Loot = ["manzana", "pera","melon","sandia","limón","durazno"];



    var Hrandom = Loot[Math.floor(Loot.length * Math.random())];


        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =""+Hrandom;
```

todavía soy noob pero le echo ganas cuando puedo.  Yo se que le falta ago.... algo me dice que le falta un IF, pero no se donde. O al tal vez un loop.

Solo quiero que salga manzana, limón...etc..no limón, limón, manzana... solo quiero que no se repita dos a 3 veces seguidas.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código entero? Me refiero, desde que le das al botón en el cual llamas al a función y la función entera a la que llamas.

Comment: Utiliza splice para sacar los elementos del arreglo después de seleccionarlos para que no se repitan. O copia los elementos que has sacado en un nuevo arreglo y usa indexOf para ver si ya lo seleccionaste antes, aunque eso puede ser poco performing.

Answer (score 1):

No entendi muy bien lo que quieres hacer, pero esto agrega los elementos de tu arreglo N veces, sin repetirlos.

```
<p id="demo"></p>

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var Loot = ["manzana", "pera","melon","sandia","limón","durazno"];
    var Hrandom = Loot[Math.floor(Loot.length * Math.random())];
    if(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML.indexOf(Hrandom) === -1){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +=" "+Hrandom+" ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Loot = ["manzana", "pera","melon","sandia","limón","durazno"];
var Hrandom;
 while(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML == ""+Hrandom){
    var Hrandom = Loot[Math.floor(Loot.length * Math.random())];
 }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =""+Hrandom;
```

Ya nunca se va a repetir

Comment: Cuidado con la estructura `while` , comprobará con la variable `Hrandom` que aún no está definida. `undefined` será el resultado

Comment: si, se me fue definirla arriba con `var Hrandom;`

Comment: No hace falta declarar la variable antes de tiempo, creo que la solución es invertir el while, mira, por ejemplo, [mi respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/27347/21) a esta misma pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Si no quieres que se repita, simplemente entra en un ciclo hasta que no sea el mismo valor que te dio la última vez.

Algo como:

```
var Loot = ["manzana", "pera","melon","sandia","limón","durazno"];
do
  var Hrandom = Loot[Math.floor(Loot.length * Math.random())];
while (""+Hrandom == document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML)
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =""+Hrandom;
```

Comment: muchachos muchas gracias, son lo mejorssss

Answer (score 0):

Os dejo aquí otro ejemplo con una función para detectar posible duplicados en un array.

```js
var Loot  = ['manzana', 'pera', 'melon', 'sandia', 'limón', 'durazno'];
var Hrandom = [];

for (var i = 0; i < Loot.length; i++) {  
  Hrandom.push(Loot[Math.floor(Loot.length * Math.random())]);        
}

function detectarDuplicado(item){
  
  var noDuplicado = [];
  
  item.forEach(function(item) {
  
      if (noDuplicado.indexOf(item) === -1) {
      
          noDuplicado.push(item);
      }
  });
  
  return noDuplicado.join(', ');
}


document.getElementById('demo').textContent = detectarDuplicado(Hrandom);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien a lo que te refieres, este sería el código de una función que al ejecutarse, escoge aleatoria-mente un elemento del arreglo, y escribe ese valor en el contenido html de una etiqueta con id demo:

```
var Loot = ["manzana", "pera","melon","sandia","limón","durazno"];

var miFuncion = function(){
  var Hrandom = Loot[Math.floor(Loot.length * Math.random())];
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Hrandom;
}
```

Ahora, para hacer clic imagino que tendrás un botón en una etiqueta html:

```
<button id="btnrandom" type="button">aleatorio</button>
```

puedes agregar a dicho botón el atributo onclick para que ejecute tu función al hacer click sobre el:

```
<button id="btnrandom" type="button" onclick="miFuncion();">aleatorio</button>
```

o por javascript:

```
document.getElementById("btnrandom").addEventListener("click",miFuncion);
```

y así cada vez que se hace clic en el botón el valor en el div con id="demo" cambiará.

Dejo el enlace de un Fiddle con el código funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/5fr29ju0/

Comment: El problema que describe es que el valor devuelto por random se repite y da los mismos valores dos veces hasta tres veces seguidas.  Igual es buena las opciones para añadir una función  al evento `click`

Comment: Toda la razón, creo que la respuesta de @jachguate esta muy bien. Gracias por la aclaración